# Roadblock setting up my Phonegap environment for Android on windows

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-3

I am new to the PhoneGap/Cordova-CLI thing (and Online Build).

I have searched on internet and studied about how can i start developing app using Awesome Phonegap.
and They say its easy to setup...!

I am using Winows 7 Ultimate 64 -bit

I have installed

1. node -V 0.10.18
2. phonegap -V 3.1.0-0.15.0
3. Cordova -V 3.1.0-0.1.0
4. java version "1.7.0"

I have set my **Java_home , ANT_Home and PATH** variables as required.

My **ANT_HOME path** is : C:\phonegap\ant\ (i.e. %ANT_HOME%/bin/..)

then I went to command Prompt (I m using ConEmu 64 bit) and typed following command

```
C:\phonegap>phonegap create phonegapone come.myapps.phonegapone phonegapone
[phonegap] created project at C:\phonegap\phonegapone
```

- Project created! then tried following command

  ```
  C:\phonegap\phonegapone>phonegap build android
  [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
  [phonegap] using the local environment
  [phonegap] adding the Android platform...
  [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
  ```

I don't understand why am i getting this error

> [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.
>   Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:

Please help me out here...

any links to proper documentation or wiki is welcome.

PS:
initially i have **started with Phonegap 3.0 and Cardova 3.0 version** and tried to build and run the application. 
I was successful till to the building of project with Android somehow. but after deploying it, it was failing with classNoFound exception.(which i guess was mostly because of Cardova Jar files version missmatch , I guess cos i never had a chance to figure it out). and today After a week when i have opened the project again to slove the problem. Upon creating a project using Phonegap crate **my phonegap and Cardova both were updated with the latest version** and i came across this very weird problem

Comment: Have you tried same commands in plain command prompt without ConEmu?

Comment: Yes , The same error.. though the error is not consistent.. some time after the error it says " Command Failed to Execute: ant jar"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue today. upon research I found that I need to install JDK instead of JRE.

[Install JDK from this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

After installation, set the JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 [your JDK Path].

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact same issue. I resolved it by using "cordova" instead of PhoneGap, so the command "cordova run android" got me a better error message (I needed to add the Android platform (via "cordova platform add android")) and then it deployed to my device successfully.